# Select method in LINQ and converting int to string value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method:

```
 public List<string> FooBar(int companyId, string countryCode)
        {
                return repository.GetAll().Where(x => countryCode == x.CountryCode && x.Services.Any(y => y.CompanyId == companyId)).Select(x => Convert.ToString(x.Id)).ToList();
        }
```

I also tried `.Select(x => x.Id.ToString())`

Im getting runtime error as follows:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
```

Comment: why do you need to convert the id to a string? Can you post your object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are doing it while the query **is not yet materialized** (it means it's not in the memory yet). This means that you are calling `.ToList()` after you are done with the conversion. If you want to convert to a string before materializing (in SQL), you need to use SqlFunctions like `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`.

What you can do is call `.ToList()` and then take `.Select(y=>y.Id.ToString()).ToList()` or use the previous method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var q= repository.GetAll().Where(x => countryCode == x.CountryCode && x.Services.Any(y => y.CompanyId == companyId)).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

return  q.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: that was initially, also breaks on the same line with same error.

Comment: @Stefan0309 you have to post repository.GetAll() then

Comment: @Stefan0309 I will never believe that c# doesn't recognize ToString()

Comment: It's not C# ... it is LINQ to Entities ... it cannot convert ToString/Conver.ToString to SQL code